# Add an argument to theme in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, structure

I have a global variable with the theme for ggplot2:

```
cPlotOpts <- opts (axis.text.x = theme_text (size=10, colour="grey50"), axis.text.y = theme_text (…
```

and I would like to add one argument to it later in the code but without modifying those already set, so that

```
axis.text.x = theme_text (size=10, colour="grey50", angle=90)
```

How can I add this one argument (`angle`) to the already defined `theme_text` without having to explicitly repeat the settings for `size` and `colour`?

[Edited after the first answer for greater clarity.]

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest approach is to just use a function.

```
cPlotOpts <- function(size = 10, colour = "grey50", ...) {
  opts(axis.text.x = theme_text (size=size, colour=colour, ...))
}
```

then to add an argument later, simply:

```
cPlotOpts(angle=90)
```

which yields:

```
cPlotOpts(angle=90)
$axis.text.x
theme_text(colour = colour, size = size, angle = 90)

attr(,"class")
[1] "options"
```

If you do not want it edited, just use `cPlotOpts()`. Is something like that acceptable?

Comment: This is a very nice solution, and I'm sure I will find use for it in the future, thank you. For my present problem, however, it isn't so great. I should have mentioned cPlotOpts contains actually quite a lot of settings for different themes (text, title, axis &c.). Changing them all to function arguments would be impractical, and besides, I wouldn't have an easy way to decide which arguments go to text themes, which to title themes and so on.

Comment: I have to think if there is another good way to do what you want. You certainl could just make the function take a single argument for the angle (i.e., you would not need to change all the options to function arguments, just the ones you want the flexibility to change).  I would also explore the `+` and `%+%` operators. One may do what you want.  Otherwise, I think the solution would involve some function that can check whether an argument has been used and if not, somehow modify the existing object to include it, which off the top of my head seems nontrivial, but perhaps someone else knows.